# What do Vue's Watcher parameters all mean?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to debug some Vue code. I am finding that some DOM elements are reacting when I'd not expect them to and vice versa. I have watched the Vue [Mastery Course on Advanced Components](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/advanced-components/reactivity-in-vue) but other than providing a rationale for Vue's reactivity, it's not getting me across the line.

Here is an example of what I see in the console:

[image]

Can you please explain the following parameters which show up in Chrome DevTools when I examine a Vue data item (an array of four objects in this case):

1. deep
2. user
3. lazy
4. sync

Extra points for (a) linking to the relevant documentation and (b) advice on debugging this aspect of Vue.

Comment: FWIW, this article was decent but insufficient: https://medium.com/dailyjs/tracing-or-debugging-vue-js-reactivity-the-computed-tree-9da0ba1df5f9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I know from the source code is this:

`deep` is easy - it checks if it needs to watch nested value changes (`root.of.my.element.changed`)

`user` is an internal variable that describes if the watcher was created by the user (in you `watch` section of the component) or was internally created one by the system

`lazy` is like other lazy modifiers - it would use an internal cache and group update events (watcher handlers); useful if you update multiple object properties at once

`sync` - that's the trickiest and what I know is based on browsing the code - it marks the watcher as synchronous. If set to true each update will fire immediately and will basically block any other code execution. Even if you don't have `lazy` set to true, watcher will still queue his callbacks, working asynchronously in order to not get any code execution blocked. `sync` will force otherwise

<sub>Additional (thanks to @Ohgodwhy):</sub>

`immediate` - will trigger the watcher's callback immediately upon component creation with variable's current value

Comment: I was writing as you responded. It's perfect. The only thing I would add is that OP is missing `immediate` which tells it to execute the function attached to it on `component creation`.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy - I'll add this one just to have the full list :)